# "P only if Q" and "Q is necessary for P" confusion

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let's consider statement "If it rains today, I will see a movie this evening." Let P="it rains today" and Q="seeing a movie this evening"

// P only if Q

Do we interpret it as: *Only if you saw a movie this evening **there is a possibility** it rained today*, because if it isn't raining you could still see a movie this evening. How can a movie guarantee rain if there is possibility that it didn't rained and you could still see a movie this evening?

// Q is a necessary condition for P

"*Seeing a movie is a necessary condition **for a possibility** that it rained today*", because you could see a movie even if it isn't raining.

Comment: It is simply, 'P implies Q', that is if it rains today, you will definitely see a movie. Thus P becomes a necessary condition for Q to happen. Q is not necessary for P to happen. It is only a one way implication.

Comment: P is a *sufficient* condition for Q to happen, not a necessary condition.  You might see a movie even if it's not raining, but if it is raining you will definitely see a movie.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you said first was right. As you said:

> Only if you saw a movie this evening there is a possibility it rained today, because if it isn't raining you could still see a movie this evening.

Unless it explicitly says that if it will *not* rain you wil *not* see a movie this evening, what is in blockquotes and what you said the first time is right.